# Cryptic exception copy/pasting from DataGridView into Excel 2002

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

Good Morning,

Running Visual Studio 2008 (C# 3.5).  DataGridView is loaded manually (not data bound).   Copy/pasting into Notepad/Wordpad works fine, but when I try to copy/paste into Excel I get this weird Exception:

`Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC))`

This was working as of last Friday.  I'm completely stumped.  I am pretty sure this has worked in the past.  I've tried rebooting, re-adding the DataGridView control.  Any help much appreciated.

Regards,
-Alan.

Comment: Are you using the default copy procedure or did you create a custom one?

Comment: Also are you opening excel by hand (opening excel then hitting paste) or are you using interop to create a instance of excel?

Comment: It seems to be a reported bug:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/97153/unhandled-comexception-invalid-formatetc and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/97153/unhandled-comexception-invalid-formatetc#
There is a comment that might help: Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> "Treat exceptions crossing appdomain boundries or managed/unmanaged boundries as unhandled"

Comment: default copy/paste.  I wrote no copy/paste code, just doing Ctrl-C in the datagrid then trying Ctrl-V in Excel.

Comment: Those bug reports are from 2005!  surely it can't be the same issue, can it?

Comment: Same problem here. I can paste just fine into excel. But this exception is thrown. As a "workaround" I've just disabled this exception. Any followup?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Getting the same prob but I couldnt find that option in Debugging... Any idea if it's been moved?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some of your data is being interpreted by Excel as a formula (like 5/0).

You could try Pat's suggestion first (it's easier!).

Also, try pasting your text into Notepad first, copying everything from Notepad, and pasting that into Excel.

If you still get the errors, try pasting the first half of the text in Notepad. If that succeeds, paste the second half. They key is to try to narrow down which string of text is causing Excel to Barf on you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject)` , try this: `Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true);`. The 'true' parameter tells the Clipboard to take a copy of the data object. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to instead of using ctrl+v to paste into excel, right click and select paste special and choose text formatting. It sounds like there is a different kind of encoding when you copy the contents to the clipboard(ctrl+c)
There are some other options available for pasting if you right click the mouse button instead of using the paste hotkey(ctrl+p).
Hopefully this helps ya out
-Pat